# Android: Get current location in onResume activity

Tags: android, android-studio, geolocation

I am trying to get current location using GPS. So First I am checking GPS is enable or not. If GPS is disable at that time am showing alert and redirect user to enable GPS from Settings. When GPS is enable then redirect Settings to my App at that time in onResume activity I am getting 0.00 current location. How can I get instant current location when enable GPS.

Thanks in advance.

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        getCurrenLocation();
    }


public void getCurrenLocation() {
        gps = new GpsTracker(GetLocation.this);
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
//        boolean gps_enabled = false;
//        boolean network_enabled = false;

        try {
            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }

        try {
            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
        if (gps_enabled && network_enabled) {

            if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (latitude != 0.0 && longitude != 0.0) {
                    txtLocation.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtLong.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtLat.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    txtLocation.setText("Your Location is - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude);
                    txtLong.setText(Double.toString(longitude));
                    txtLat.setText(Double.toString(latitude));
                }

                Log.d("latitude onResume:: :: :: ::", String.valueOf(latitude));
                Log.d("longitude onResume:: :: :: ::", String.valueOf(longitude));
            }
        } else if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            alertDialog();
        }
    }
```

Comment: "How can I get instant current location when enable GPS" You can't. That's not how GPS technology works. You'll have to request location and wait for updates

Comment: It's not instant, and you need a LocationListener or you wont get any updates. http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html

Comment: Did you find a good foolproof solution? I'm looking for something similar.

Answer (score 2):

@komal It always take time to get the Location , depending upon the provider and the place . GPS take signal from min 3 satellite and do   uses trilateration  , so depending upon the signal strength and ur location it could take time . Even Google Map app take upto 10 sec to get Lat/Lng sometime. You should use [FusedLocationProvider](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html) from Google Play services

Try this demo https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/tree/master/LocationUpdates

Comment: Right!!  it's taking time to get LatLong

Comment: For instant location u can get the last known location only , or else Run a service and request location update to 10 metre and 100 ms , but it will drain u battery .

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the permission to your manifest?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I think it is not possible to get the location immediately after enabling GPS. GPS needs to fix the ambiguities and estimate your location.
If you need a location immediately you can you the coarse location. However, this location is much inaccurate than GPS.

Comment: Yes i have already  added 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

Answer (score -1):

Try this class to get the latitude and longitude

```
import android.app.AlertDialog.Builder;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;

 public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {


 private Context context;

 boolean isGPSEnabled=false;
 boolean isNetworkEnabled=false;
 boolean canGetLocation=false;

 Location location;

 double latitude;
 double longitude;

 private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES=10;
 private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES=1000*60*1;

 protected LocationManager locationManager;

 public GPSTracker(Context context)
  {
 this.context=context;
 getLocation();
   }

  public Location getLocation()
  {
  try{
   locationManager=(LocationManager)     context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
  isGPSEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
  isNetworkEnabled=locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);




if(!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled)
{
    showSettingsAlert();
}
else{
    this.canGetLocation=true;
    if(isNetworkEnabled)
    {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);


    if(locationManager !=null)
    {
        location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if(location !=null)
    {
        latitude=location.getLatitude();
        longitude=location.getLongitude();
    }
    }
    }

    if(isGPSEnabled){
        if(location==null)
        {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

            if(locationManager !=null)
            {
                location=locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                if(location !=null)
                {
                    latitude=location.getLatitude();
                    longitude=location.getLongitude();
                }   

            }

        }
    }


}


}
catch(Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return location;
}

 public void stopUsingGPS()
  {
   if(locationManager !=null)
    {
     locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
  }

  public double getLatitude()
 {
   if(location!=null)
     {
     latitude=location.getLatitude();
     }
   return latitude;

 }


public double getLongitude()
{
  if(location!=null)
   {
    longitude=location.getLongitude();
   }
  return longitude;

}

public boolean canGetLocation(){

 return this.canGetLocation;

  }

  public void showSettingsAlert(){
  Builder alertDialog=new Builder(context);
 alertDialog.setTitle("GPS Settings");
 alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled.Do you want to go to the settings menu?");
 alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

     @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}); 

alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();

    }
});
alertDialog.show();
}


@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
return null;
 }


 }
```

And then

```
GPSTracker gps;

public void getCurrenLocation() {
    gps = new GPSTracker(classname.this);

    if (gps.canGetLocation) {
        double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
        double longitude = gps.getLongitude();
                }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks but still it's geting 0.0 when I'm calling getCurrenLocation() at "onResume"

Comment: did u try this on a device?emulators sometimes wont show gps co-ordinates

Comment: Yeah I did it, it's not getting in device

Comment: People seriously need to stop spreading this "GPSTracker" code example which is very bad and has been the cause for an awful lot of problems around world for several years by now. It's just so bad. Please save the human kind and stop spreading bad advice. [Please see this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29423025/q-android-gps-location#answer-29423818)